# how to insert value based on a subquery within a subquery

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, winforms

I have a table which is needed to be updated from a windows form, i am able to update the displayed values into the table where as i am unable to update a particular column where the value to be updated must be a reference value of the displayed data on windows form. The reference value is in another table. Following is the code:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblComplaints (ComplaintID, Description,ComplaintTypeID,ReceivedDate,ComplaintTypeID)VALUES('" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + dateTimePicker1.Text + "',???)";
```

The question mark(???) within the code is what I require.
To be more precise ComplaintTypeName is being displayed in the form in comboBox1 whereas I require its ID to be updated whose values are present in tblComplaintType

Comment: You should not use the text values of a textbox directly in a query like that - if the text contains a single quote character, the remainder of the text is interpreted as SQL instead of data, breaking the application for honest users and allowing malicious users to for instance delete all data.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you assigned the ComboBox values somehow like this in advance

```
ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
item.Text = "Item text1";
item.Value = 12;
comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

you could do the following:

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblComplaints " +
    "(ComplaintID, Description, ComplaintTypeID, ReceivedDate, ComplaintTypeID) " +
    "VALUES (@Description,@ComplaintTypeID,@ReceivedDate,@ComplaintTypeID)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", TextBox7.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplaintTypeID", TextBox10.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ReceivedDate", dateTimePicker1.Text);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ComplaintTypeID", comboBox1.SelectedValue);
```

Note that I stripped the `ComplaintID` from the sql command. Since this is a INSERT statement, you're likely to get a generated ID for that record. If that's not the case you'll have to provide another parameter in the command.

Additionally you should always parameterize your commands instead of building them via string concatenation to prevent sql injection.

Comment: No, I do not want the combobox value to be added. I require its respective ID to be added. For Example: My second table is somewhat like it has the following two columns [ID, Name], now my form is displaying Name, i want ID to be inserteted into my tblComplaint

Comment: The `Value` usually represents its ID, the `Text` holds the textual representation

Comment: I have iserted combobox1 values using combobox tasks option available in visual studio

Comment: Have a look at [this property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: No, what you are passing above is not correct when it comes to complainttypeid, as complainttype will be displayed in the combobox, what i need is the complainttypeid of the complainttype present in table tblcomplainttype to be passed into complaints table.